# Can I put ads from more than one Google AdSense publisher under one site/page?

Tags: google-adsense, cdn, ajax

I have a Google AdSense **Personal** account and recently for some reasons I HAVE TO open a **company** account. Since an personal account can't be changed to a company one, I have to register a new one, with new publisher ID, then I need to replace my ads codes.

My page is running under a CDN, and it has some AJAX requests on each page so there might be two situations after my switch:

1. Two different publisher ads will be put under one site. This is very likely to happen because I can't control user cache
2. Two different publisher ads will be put in one page. This is unlikely to happen, but that can still happen since some part of my pages is loaded via AJAX which can be cached.

I know that AdSense has a lot of regulations and restrictions, and I don't want to challenge any of their rules and get myself into trouble, so I'd like to ask for professional suggestions for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User Gracey says in [this Google Product Forum](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/FeYexnSI-9Y/tprJSToDWosJ):

> You can use ads for more than one pub-ID on a website, however, you are still restricted to a total of 3 adsense ad units and 3 adsense links units on any page (not 3 for each pub-ID, 3 in total).

Here is [another Google Product Forum](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/L_waErm_v-c/itPPwpYOKeQJ) where user i4c claims:

> Google states "Publishers are permitted to place ad code from different AdSense accounts on the same page as long as the owner of the website has given permission for ads to be placed on their site, and the webpage complies with our program policies.
>
> A publisher will only be credited for clicks and impressions on the ad units associated with their account. Additionally, publishers are responsible for monitoring each webpage upon which their ad code appears to ensure compliance with our policies."

Mixing and matching AdSense IDs is not a problem as long as you don't have too many ads on the page.